# How to create a page showing certain roles?

Tags: 7

I want to create a page that shows the organisation of the group behind the website. To do this, I would like to render a list of certain Drupal roles, along with every user that has that role. However, I have no idea how to do this without writing a custom module. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view (using [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)) of users with a grouping by role. You can add a filter for the specific roles that you want to include.

Comment: Wait, so I would need to create a new node of content type Person for each user that I would like to display: That seems like double work...

Comment: Updated my answer, I wasn't sure if the people were Drupal users with Drupal roles

Answer (score 1):

You can also display drupal user based on role. If want to add more fields for user profile, use profile 2 module.

Or if you want to create user profile as content then you need to create a content type with a taxonomy Field (add taxonomy with name role). To shows the contents use views and grouped the content based on taxonomy terms.

Comment: How could I display the users per role? That's what I've been trying to find out :/ As for the content type: Would I need to create a new profile node for each user manually?

Comment: Just create a views for user and grouped the user based on user role

Comment: If wanna mange user as content then you need to create a content type for user and add a taxonomy Field in content type. Then create a view to display user content and grouped based taxonomy terms(roles). But you can't use these content for login purpose.